# SQL Injection Stored Procedures

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-injection

I am learning about SQL injections and wanted to try one.

I created a web app and created a stored procedure to access some info to my database.

Here is my stored procedure and the code in the asp .net app

```
Create Procedure spTest
(
    @UserName varchar(20),
    @UserPwd varchar(max)
)
AS
Begin
Declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'select UserName,UserPwd from Users where UserName='''+ @UserName+ ''' 
                                                And UserPwd = '''+ @UserPwd + ''' '
Exec(@sql)
End
```

C# code:

```
string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTest",con);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName",txtUserName.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPwd", txtPassword.Text);
   con.Open();
   SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   dr.Read();
   if (dr.HasRows)
   {
       labelLogin.Text = "Logged in";
   }
   else 
   { 
      labelLogin.Text = "Not logged in"; 
   }
```

In the textbox for username, I input `bobby' or 1=1--`

"bobby" is an invalid username.

Now, I thought the app would login with the fake username because 1=1 is always true and the rest of the SQL statement is commented out.

But, it shows "Not logged " What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: A parameterized query - as you have constructed here - encodes its values to prevent SQL injection.  If you're serious about writing an injectable query, you must write the value directly into your query using a StringBuilder or concatenation.

Comment: How to do that with Stored Procedures? I have been reading that stored procedures are not necessarily safe from sql injections, unless you use parametrized queries. But how do I use it in the code? I can't find anywhere how to use stored procedures without parameters. I google "stored procedures sql injection", but the tutorials i find all explain the wrong way to create stored procedures but not how to use in the asp .net code.

Comment: I did it with sql statements but I don't know how to do it with stored procedures.

Comment: Pretty much the same way - your procedure would need to construct and then execute SQL without checking its safety.

Comment: The key is to build the query in the stored procedure and then use `EXEC` to execute the string.  Bad things are easy to accomplish that way.  The technique is generally refered to as _dynamic SQL_, something you might search for.

Comment: I tried your example with `bobby' or 1=1--` and I get "Logged in".

Comment: @GalacticCowboy **Parameterized queries do not encode values!** If that's what you think, you've missed the point. Parameterized queries ***segregate*** the data values from the code of the query.

Comment: Try printing out your sql before you exec() it.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone. It's "working" now. I "refreshed" the database and somehow it's "working" now.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn correct, I mis-stated that.  However, using DbCommand.Parameters is intended to help protect against injection because the value of a parameter is treated as a literal value and not interpreted.  (In other words, the single quote embedded within it does not terminate the command as the injector intends.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you only enter bobby' OR 1=1 --' as username? It will still try to match Password since it is on a seperate line. It should work if you combine it with a valid password or enter bobby' OR 1=1 --' as password  too.

First case:

```
select UserName,UserPwd from Users 
where UserName='bobby' OR 1=1 --'
And UserPwd = 'xyz'
```

Second case:

```
    select UserName,UserPwd from Users 
    where 'UserName'='bobby' OR 1=1 --'
    And 'UserPwd' = 'bobby' OR 1=1 --'
```

First case equals:

```
select UserName,UserPwd from Users 
where 
    UserName='bobby' OR 
    (1=1 And UserPwd = 'xyz')
```

Second case equals:

```
select UserName,UserPwd from Users 
where 'UserName'='bobby' OR
    (1=1 And 'UserPwd' = 'bobby') OR 
    1=1
```

Comment: bobby' or 1=1--
is the username he is entering. The '--' at the end mean that everything after that becomes a comment so in theory the SQL statement becomes:

select UserName,UserPwd from Users where UserName='bobby' or 1=1
which will return ALL usernames and passwords.

Comment: No, the AND is on a different row, at least that's how it looks.

Comment: I will be marking digscoop's post as answer to close the topic as the issue has been fixed. Thanks all!!

Comment: It won't be on a different row.  There is no carriage return in the @sql variable.

Comment: It will. The newline is between red characters, so it is in the string.